# How to put sounds in an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 10 sounds, and it would be easier for me to put them into an array. However I'm new to Obj C.

Here is the code so far, this is just for 1 sound. I could copy and paste it 10 times. But if all 10 sounds are in an array I'll be able to do more functions with the sounds.

```
- (IBAction)oneSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vocal 1" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (oneAudio) [oneAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    oneAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    oneAudio.delegate = self;
    [oneAudio play];    


}
```

thanks

Comment: Which object do you want to put in the array? Have you looked for a tutorial on Objective-C and arrays? Here's one: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/08/26/objective-c-tutorial-nsarray/ Here's the Apple docs on collections: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF.

Comment: Well basically 10 sounds, so would the object be the sounds?

Comment: Knowing what an object is and how to add one to an array is pretty much rock-bottom basics, and it sounds like you need to read a tutorial or two first, try something out, and come back here if you have a specific difficulty. Walking you through this is not really what SO is for.

Answer (score 1):

Heres one way,

```
NSMutableArray *soundArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[soundArray addObject:oneAudio];
.
.
.
[soundArray addObject:tenAudio];
```

or you could also put the paths to the audio content into the Array and instantiate them when required.

Comment: I would recommend storing the paths to the sounds, as strings, in the array, and creating sound objects only when needed. Sound objects might require a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Take the file paths of the arrays, make them into strings, add THOSE to the array, and access them only when needed, or else you'll be using up a lot of memory.